# firefox issue with bottom padding

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox

I've attached a screenshot of the code working on Google Chrome. But that same code doesn't have the same effect in Firefox (typical!). Does anyone know what I need to put in so both browsers work correctly.

```
.carousel-holder { 
    position: relative; 
    width: 877px !important; 
    margin-left: 30px; 
}
.carousel-overlay { 
    background: url('../img/overlay.png') top left no-repeat; 
    width: 877px; 
    height: 151px; 
    position: relative; 
    bottom: 142px; 
    left: 0px; 
    margin-right: 56px;
}
```

Chrome - http://tinypic.com/r/2mq98w0/5 
Firefox - http://tinypic.com/r/zwi8w1/5 
URL - http://www.mangdevelopment.co.uk/crk/

Comment: Check your premises. Chrome is a lot more "Forgiving" when it comes to css, whereas Firefox is relatively stricter. Test on Opera, you'll see for sure if your css has problems.

Comment: And please do post the HTML with this too.

Comment: @Harsh well probably not with the current Opera since it should render it the same as Chrome because of the same engine.

Comment: @user2686158 I'm pretty sure it is because of the negative margin of `.crossbg` and [margin collapsing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin_collapsing) which is done right in FireFox but not in Chrome. So in my opinion FireFox displays it correct.

Comment: @t.niese: oh, Opera/Blink came out? I haven't been online enough :)
But Opera 12 was good, and although I never used it, it did help me solve a few critical bugs in my own css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is with your `.crossbg` class

Replace `margin-top: -230px` with `top: -230px`

Comment: Perfect, thank you. 
Although this fixed it, the footer is now far above the bottom, something to do with the same code maybe do you think?

Comment: @user2686158 changing position with `relative` keeps the _reserved/used space_ in place and only moves the visual part.

Comment: geez, Chrome is misguiding a lot of unsuspecting folks with its generous rendering...

Comment: @user2686158: If the footer is giving you trouble, one way to fix this is to change your markup a little, Move `.crossbg` into the carousel holder, and set `position: absolute` and then position accordingly. Will require some work, but should work